# InitializeCriticalSectionEx is not member of global namespace in atlwinverapi.h

Tags: c++, sdk, visual-studio-2017, atl, preprocessor

I have recently moved from vs 2013 to vs 2017. we have this project that has these preprocessor Definitions:

```
WIN32
DRG_BUILD_DLL
WINVER=0x0600
```

Now in `atlwinverapi.h` I get this error that `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` is not a member of global namespace. Any ideas why this problem is happening?

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA) && !defined(_USING_V110_SDK71_) && !defined(_ATL_XP_TARGETING)
    // InitializeCriticalSectionEx is available in Vista or later, desktop or store apps
    return ::InitializeCriticalSectionEx(lpCriticalSection, dwSpinCount, Flags);
```

Comment: What happens if you increase `WINVER` definition and Rebuild?  See [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx).  Also make sure you are including `"Windows.h"` before `"atlwinverapi.h"` as noted here: [InitializeCriticalSectionEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683477(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @PhilBrubaker  Increasing `WINVER` didn't help. I already tried that.  I only have `atlwinverapi.h` as external dependency so I am not including in directly. I checked `atlevent.h` and there it is included without `windows.h`

Comment: I see that `"atlwinverapi.h"` does include `"Windows.h"`.  I would suspect that somewhere there is another definition of `"WINVER"` that is blocking the `InitializeCriticalSectionEx()` function from being exposed as a declaration.

Comment: You can troubleshoot that scenario by using the Proprocess to file feature.  See here: [-P Preprocess to a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx)

Comment: @PhilBrubaker Thanks for the tip, will try it and report back if it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this error, because a header (written for MSVC12) included

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x502 //NTDDI_VERSION
```

The fix was to delete this line.

This fixed it because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um\synchapi.h` contains

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
    InitializeCriticalSectionEx(
        _Out_ LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection,
        _In_ DWORD dwSpinCount,
        _In_ DWORD Flags
    );
#endif // (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
```