# Intel TBB - 'InitializeCriticalSectionEx': identifier not found compiler error

Tags: c++, c++17, tbb, poco-libraries, vcpkg

I have a VS (C++) project that relies on OpenCV and TBB, so I created property sheets for each library and included them in the project. Everything worked fine and the code compiled.

Yesterday, I have started using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) package manager. I installed OpenCV and TBB via vcpkg and everything seemed to work. I created an empty project, included the headers of both and tested if the new compiled libraries work. After verifying that, I went back to my main project and removed the property sheets, so I can use the libraries from vcpkg. I did not change the code in any way since the last successful compilation.

But when I try to compile the code now I get this error two times (in main.cpp and in a submodule)

> tbb\critical_section.h(53): error C3861: 'InitializeCriticalSectionEx': identifier not found

Does anybody know what is going on here or why this error occurs?

### Update

I found the error myself. I'm adding the poco-libraries tag, because it's actually a conflict between TBB and Poco.

Comment: It could depend on [what Windows version the project is targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154505/initializecriticalsectionex-is-not-member-of-global-namespace-in-atlwinverapi-h)

Comment: @BoPersson It kinda did. I've posted an answer to explain the problem in detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the source of the problem and it has actually nothing to do with TBB but with the [Poco library](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco).

Consider the minimum example:

```
#include <Poco/Poco.h>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

void main()
{   
}
```

This will throw an compiler error.

## Tracing down the path

When including *tbb.h*, *critical_section.h* is included in line 51 of *tbb.h*. However, *ciritcal_section.hpp* includes *machine/winwdows_api.h* which looks like this (unnecessary stuff is cut out):

**tbb/machine/winwdows_api.h:**

```
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64

#include <windows.h>

#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600

#define InitializeCriticalSectionEx inlineInitializeCriticalSectionEx

inline BOOL WINAPI inlineInitializeCriticalSectionEx( LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection, DWORD dwSpinCount, DWORD )
{
    return InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount( lpCriticalSection, dwSpinCount );
}
#endif
```

As you can see, *windows.h* is included **before** the check of the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro. This macro is defined in *sdkddkver.h* (which is included in *windows.h*), iff it's not already defined (in my case it's set to Win10):

**sdkddkver.h:**

```
#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_CHICAGO_)
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0A00
#endif
```

In *windows.h*, the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro controls which version of the windows header files are actually included. If `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to an earlier version than Windows Vista, the function `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` is not defined.

This issue is catched by *machine/winwdows_api.h* (as you can see in the code block of that file) by simply defining a macro `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` that calls an appropriate alternative function.

So far so good.

## The problem

The root of all evil lies in *Poco/UnWindows.h* of the Poco library. When including a poco header, at some point *UnWindows.h* will be included.

**Poco/UnWindows.h** (shortened):

```
#if defined(_WIN32_WINNT)
    #if (_WIN32_WINNT < 0x0501)
        #error Unsupported Windows version.
    #endif
#elif defined(NTDDI_VERSION)
    #if (NTDDI_VERSION < 0x05010100)
        #error Unsupported Windows version.
    #endif
#elif !defined(_WIN32_WINNT)
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
    #define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010100
#endif
#endif    

#include <windows.h>
```

The preprocessor checks, if `_WIN32_WINNT` is already defined, and if not, sets it to 0x0501 which is Windows XP. **After** that, *windows.h* is included. In the previous chapter I mentioned that `_WIN32_WINNT` controls which version of the windows header files are actually included.

Now imagine, the very first include in our project is a header from Poco. This means, that `_WIN32_WINNT` will be set to Windows XP and *windows.h* will include the windows headers of *Windows XP* (which imo is already a bad sign).

But don't worry, it gets worse.

If we trace the include hierarchy one level up, we reach *Poco/Platform_WIN32.h*.

**Poco/Platform_WIN32.h** (shortened):

```
#include "Poco/UnWindows.h"
...
    #if defined (_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE)
        #ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
            #undef _WIN32_WINNT
        #endif
        #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE
...
```

Funny, isn't it? First, it includes *UnWindows.h*, which sets `_WIN32_WINNT` and causes Windows XP headers to be included, and next it redefines `_WIN32_WINNT` to be Windows 8.1. I have no clue why it does that, maybe there is a good reason, idk.

If we now look at the minimum example at the very top we see that Poco is included before TBB. What now happens is:

1. Include Poco headers
2. Set `_WIN32_WINNT` to Windows XP
3. Include windows headers (Windows XP version, because of 2)
4. Reset `_WIN32_WINNT` to Windows 8.1
5. Include TBB headers (windows headers are already included, so TBB doesn't need to include them again in *tbb/windows_api.h*)
6. TBB checks the windows version via `_WIN32_WINNT` and recognizes Windows 8.1 (as set by Poco)
7. TBB thinks `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` is defined, because the Windows version is 8.1 (or is it? Poco says: get rekt) and `InitializeCriticalSectionEx` is defined since Windows Vista.
8. Unfortunately Poco ensured that the Windows XP headers are loaded, so compiler says: no.

## The solution

Either include *windows.h* yourself beforehand, or set `_WIN32_WINNT` yourself beforehand:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00    // either this
#include <Windows.h>           // or this

#include <Poco/Poco.h>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

void main()
{   
}
```

Maybe someone of the Poco contributors can clarify some things here. The Poco version is 1.8.1-1 built with x64 (via vcpkg).

### Update

Poco is on the issue. Updates can be found [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2306).